# Urbanairhsip.apk not found Android Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, urbanairship.com

I am trying to add Urbanairship to my Android app.
In Eclipse, I have imported the library, gone to "Properties > Android" and added the library, but when I build the app I am getting the following error in the console:

```
urbanairship-lib] Could not find urbanairship-lib.apk!
```

This is driving me crazy! I have followed the Urbanairship guide for android at http://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android.html and also tried to search for a solution but I can't understand this error.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! TIA

Comment: try to clean build your project in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you imported the "urbanairship-lib" directory as the project and not the entire zip. Verify the project is marked as a library by right clicking urbanairship-lib -> Properties -> Android -> check is Library. Then do clean all the projects (Project -> clean -> All Projects).

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject